# Printing string is different from adding to list, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistwidget

I have the following code:

```
if len(itemName) < 31:
                while len(itemName) < 31:
                    itemName = itemName+"-"
            itemName = itemName + self.convert_size(info.st_size)
            while len(itemName) < 48:
                itemName = itemName+"-"
            itemName = itemName + datetime.fromtimestamp(info.st_ctime).strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
            print(itemName)
```

which prints this:
[image]

which is exactly what I want, all sizes and dates starting at the same positions for all files (aligned).

Now I add this line after the print statement: `self.file_list.addItem(itemName)`

Which in Qt is basically adding an item to a list.
Here's a screenshot of how it looks on the list:
[image]

As you can see sizes and dates are not aligned/starting at same positions.

My questions is why an how can I fix the problem?
It prints it out just fine but when adding to a QListWidget, it does not look the same.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `your_listwidget.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Monospace"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a matter of the font that `Qt` is using, it is using a font that is not monospace, i.e: different characters have different sizes, to use a monospace font that displays all characters with the same size, change the `Qt` font to `consolas` (preferably) or `Courier New` or any other monospace font.